# npm install Error while executing: npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I created a new branch from sprint, and trying r=to run npm install and it fails with below errors

I have tried running npm install -g npm and didnt work

[image: the termonal console is here]

any help is appreciated :-)